# Presto SQL - Converting a date string to date format

Tags: sql, presto

I'm on presto and have a date formatted as varchar that looks like -

```
7/14/2015 8:22:39 AM
```

I've looked the presto docs and tried various things(cast, date_format, using split_part to parse and then cast) and am not getting this to convert to a date format that I can use with functions like date_diff.

I've tried:

```
cast(fieldname as timestamp)
date_format(fieldname, '%Y-%m-%d %T)
```

Both give me an error like this

```
'Value cannot be cast to timestamp: 3/31/2016 6:05:04 PM'
```

How do I convert this?

Comment: I think problem is with date format. Can you change the format like this `2016-03-31 6:05:04 PM` and cast it ?

Comment: You should try the ISO 8601 format "2016-03-31 18:05:04". I'm almost certain it should work

Comment: @coladict i tried `select cast('2016-03-31 6:05:04 PM' as timestamp)` and this doesnt work either

Comment: Not `6:05:04 PM`, it has to be `06:05:04` for AM and `18:05:04` for PM.

Comment: @coladict that might be a formatting issue with the data but that leading 0 is what the cast should fix. But even when i add the leading 0 to the above example, i still get the same error.

Comment: did you try an ANSI SQL timestamp literal? `timestamp '2016-03-31 18:05:04'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i figured it out. answer below.

Answer (score 75):

I figured it out. The below works in converting it to a 24 hr date format.

```
select date_parse('7/22/2016 6:05:04 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

See [`date_parse` documentation in Presto](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse).

Comment: Just be aware that if you want a date from this you have to explicitly cast it back to date (from timestamp) - just using a format like '%Y-%m-%d' is not enough...

Answer (score 17):

You can also do something like this

date(cast('2016-03-22 15:19:34.0' as timestamp))

Answer (score 5):

Use: `cast(date_parse(inv.date_created,'%Y-%m-%d %h24:%i:%s') as date)`

Input: `String timestamp`

Output: `date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'`

Answer (score 4):

Converted DateID having date in Int format to date format: Presto Query

```
Select CAST(date_format(date_parse(cast(dateid as varchar(10)), '%Y%m%d'), '%Y/%m-%d') AS DATE)
from
     Table_Name
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

```sql
    select date_format(date_parse(t.payDate,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S'),'%Y-%m-%d') as payDate 
    from testTable  t 
    where t.paydate is not null and t.paydate <> '';
```

Answer (score 3):

If your string is in ISO 8601 format, you can also use [from_iso8601_timestamp](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

`date_format` requires first argument as `timestamp` so not the best way to convert a string. Use `date_parse` instead.

Also, use `%c` for non zero-padded month, `%e` for non zero-padded day of the month and `%Y` for four digit year.

```
SELECT date_parse('7/22/2016 6:05:04 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %r')
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2003 standard defines the format as follows:

```
<unquoted timestamp string> ::= <unquoted date string> <space> <unquoted time string>
<date value> ::= <years value> <minus sign> <months value> <minus sign> <days value>
<time value> ::= <hours value> <colon> <minutes value> <colon> <seconds value>
```

There are some definitions in between that just link back to these, but in short `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` with optional `.mmm` milliseconds is required to work on all SQL databases.

Comment: yeah but it's got something to do with the AM/PM. If I do `select cast('2016-03-31 6:05:04 PM' as timestamp)` it doesnt work. but if i remove am/pm and do `select cast('2016-03-31 6:05:04' as timestamp)` then it works. but i need the am/pm or convert to 24 hour.

Comment: If you insist on using the non-standard `3/31/2016 6:05:04 PM` according to the documentation, the format is `%c/%e/%y %r`. Have a look https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Comment: that's how my data is formatted. i'm willing to reformat but dont know how. that's my question. per the comment above, if i do `date_format('7/22/2016 6:05:04 PM', '%c/%e/%y %r')` that gives me an error too

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to convert from timestamp to date, you can also `date()` function, just like mySQL:

```
select date(your_date_colunm_name) as new_date_colunm
```