# How to extract day/month/year etc from varchar date field, using Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I currently have tables with dates, set up as VARCHAR in the format of YYYY-MM-DD such as:

```
2017-01-01
```

The date column I'm working with is called 'event_dt'

I'm used to being able to use `day(event_dt), month(event_dt), year(event_dt)` etc. in Hive, but Presto just gives me `error executing query` with no other explanation when the queries fail.

So, for example, I've tried:

```
select
month(event_dt)
from
my_sql_table
where
event_dt = '2017-01-01'
```

I would expect the output to read:

```
01
```

but all I get is `[Code: 0, SQL State: ]  Error executing query`

I've tried a few other methods listed in the Presto documentation but am having no luck at all. I realize this is probably very simple but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See that post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880540/presto-sql-converting-a-date-string-to-date-format.  You have first to convert your varchar to a date type.

Comment: `where event_dt = date '2017-01-01'` ?

Comment: @LukStorms yes I'm able to specify in my where clause using that, as well as a range such as 'between '2017-01-01' and '2017-03-03' but I'm also looking for ways to have my output give a column with year/month/day etc included

Comment: oh, that date column is actually a varchar.  Does something like this give an error? `select month(cast('2019-10-15' as date))`

Comment: @LukStorms yes! Thank you, that worked. Are you able to point me to a specific piece of documentation you used to find that?

Comment: There's some documentation [here](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html).  But CAST is standard SQL that works in almost any DBMS, so I figured presto would also know it

Comment: @LukStorms I'm also trying to sum a field 'revenue' which is a BIGINT datatype, but simply using sum(revenue) isn't working - is there some type of CAST I need to be doing here as well? I thought you could just sum bigints?

Comment: Well, I don't actually know presto, nor know some online tester for it. But from other SO posts I believe it should work if it's really a BIGINT.  If it's a varchar then cast it to bigint?  Also, presto should even have the [TRY_CAST](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html) function, which would return a NULL on invalid tekst instead of crashing on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`month()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#month) function after converting the `varchar` to a `date` with the [`date()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date) function:

```
presto> select month(date('2017-01-01'));
 _col0
-------
     1
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @LukStorms in the comments to the original question, I've found two solutions:

1. Using month(cast(event_dt as date))
2. Using month(date(event_dt))