# Presto-Sql : Converting time in string format to date format

Tags: sql, presto

In presto, I have a date formatted as varchar that looks like below :

```
 10:46:00
```

I need to cast this in timestamp. I have tried few but presto throwing errors as

> Value cannot be cast to date:10:46:00 and Value cannot be cast to
>   timestamp:10:46:00

```
select cast('10:46:00' as DATE) from abc;

select cast('10:46:00' as TIMESTAMP) from abc;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presto SQL - Converting a date string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880540/presto-sql-converting-a-date-string-to-date-format)

Comment: so what is the output of your sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below query it will solve your problem.

**Input Query in Presto:**

select (hour(date_parse(CheckStartTime,'%T')) + 1) as hr from TableName;

**CheckStartTime:**

Column name(varchar) of the table in the format of '12:32:20'.

**Output:**

13 (it will add one hour to the input time)

Comment: This is what i was looking for... It worked for me Thank you!